# How can I prevent browserify from choosing modules of a dependency?

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify

I have a common JS library, let's just call it common-lib. It depends on jQuery.

I have a project called ProjectA, it depends on both common-lib AND jQuery.

I have used npm link to have a symlink to common-lib in ProjectA.

When I build ProjectA, jQuery gets included twice, which messes up some global event handling (specifically I doing $(document).ajaxError()).

Considering that common-lib is not meant to be used on its own, I figure the best approach would be to say that common-lib needs jQuery but not include in its list of dependencies and any project relying on common-lib must provide jQuery themselves.

But this does not work. Browserify insists on looking in node_modules/common-lib/node_modules/jquery instead of node_modules/jquery.

Is there a way around this situation?

Comment: are you sure they are using same version of jQuery?

Comment: yes they are both using jquery v2.2.4